# Como obter a data atual no MySql?

Tags: mysql

pretendo criar um evento para que todas as horas verique se a data de expiração do anuncio é superior a data actual, neste caso ele deverá alterar um topico deste anuncio na base de dados, ou seja, seria algo do genero disto que eu tentei, mas tenho duvida em como obter a data instantanea:

```
    CREATE EVENT e
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
    DO UPDATE anuncios SET estado=3 WHERE dataexpiracao > -data actual-
```

Answer (score 9):

Basta usar [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

```
CREATE EVENT e
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
DO UPDATE anuncios SET estado=3 WHERE dataexpiracao > NOW()
```

Comment: Ok agradeço imenso

Answer (score 6):

Basta usar a função `NOW()`

Ex:

```
SELECT NOW()
```

Return:

> 2015-04-29 12:07:45

Segue documentação: [NOW](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp)

Comment: ok Obrigado pela ajuda